# Updating existing ftl in keycloak theme to redirect after user registration

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak

I am running keycloak 16.1.1 (jboss/keycloak) using docker-compose. I have enabled user registration and I am able to get to the registration page from my application. Basically the registration process works just fine.

What I want to do now is after the user has completed the registration process I want them to be redirected back to my application (or any other webpage). Right now, they are directed to a user account console page.

I have tried to edit the `/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/base/login/register.ftl` file to include a redirect uri in the form tag.

This is what the form tag looks like before: `<form id="kc-register-form" class="${properties.kcFormClass!}" action="${url.registrationAction}" method="post">`

And this is what it looks like after: `<form id="kc-register-form" class="${properties.kcFormClass!}" action="${url.registrationAction}?redirect_uri=http://my_application_endpoint" method="post">`

The way I am changing this line is using `sed` after running a shell for that keycloak container. Here is the command:

```
sed -i 's|<form id="kc-register-form" class="${properties.kcFormClass!}" action="${url.registrationAction}" method="post">|<form id="kc-form-login" action="${url.lo
ginAction}?redirect_uri=http://my_application_endpoint" method="post">|' /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/base/login/register.ftl
bash-4.4$ cat register.ftl
```

When I restart this container (image) and follow the process of registration what I expect is a successful registration and then the redirection. However, what I get is a message saying `Your login attempt timed out. Login will start from the beginning.`

[image]

Please advise if I'm doing something wrong or missing something entirely. Thanks!